# Don't delete exist data with SSMA

Tags: sql-server, migration, sybase, ssma

I'm trying to use Microsoft's [SQL Server Migration Assistant for Sybase 5.3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh302816%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) ('SSMA') to migrate multiple Sybase databases (that have the same schema) to a single MSSQL database.

The first database migrated fine. But when I try to migrate data from the next one, I see lots of warnings like:

```
The table 'MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable' contains data.
If you continue with data migration, all data in the table will be deleted.
```

I don't want the existing data to be deleted, but can't find a way to do this in SSMA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to go to *Tools > Options > General > Migration* and set *Extended data migration options* to *Show*.

Then I had a new *Data Mig...* tab for each table, and had to uncheck *Truncate SQL Server table* and hit *Apply* individually for each table. Rather laborious when you have a lot of tables... but it worked.